# scala DataFrame selectExpr accepting one parameter or two?

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand someone's scala code (which was built and running fine) has:

```
  // df is of type DataFrame
  df.selectExpr("*", clause)
```

While looking at this link for DataFrame: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, 
the syntax for the selectExpr has this signature below which seems accepting only one parameter:

```
    def  selectExpr(exprs: String*): DataFrame
```

So why the code I mentioned above passed in two parameters instead of one?

And what is "String*"?  It shows it is of type "scala.Predef.String", but hard to find a clear example online talking about the use of "String* as a type.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asterisk after type name is just a Scala way to define repeated parameters (see [SLS §4.6.3](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters)), that are very similar to [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) in Java.

So method declaration

```scala
def selectExpr(exprs: String*): DataFrame = { /*...*/ }
```

is roughly equivalent to Java version

```java
public DataFrame selectExpr(String... exprs) { /*...*/ }
```

and creates a method that accepts from zero to probably-as-many-as-you'll-ever-want `String` arguments.